# Extracting Sms in an xml file

Tags: android

```
     //checksms returning list sms
private ArrayList<Sms> checkSms() {
Uri uriSMSURI = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
Cursor cur = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(uriSMSURI, null, null, null, null);
while (cur.moveToNext()) 
{
newSms.setsender(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
myList.add(newSms);
}   
createXml();
return (myList);
}
```

//here createXml methode

```
private void createXml() {
File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/SmsFile.xml");
try
{Log.v(BackupFragment.this.getClass().getName(), "create file:" +  newxmlfile.createNewFile());} 
catch (IOException e)
{Log.e("IOException", "exception in createNewFile() method");}
FileOutputStream fileos = null;
try 
{fileos = new FileOutputStream(newxmlfile);}
catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
{Log.e("FileNotFoundException", "can't create FileOutputStream");}
XmlSerializer serializer = Xml.newSerializer();
try {
serializer.setOutput(fileos, "UTF-8");
serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true));
serializer.setFeature("http://xmlpull.org/v1/doc/features.html#indent-output",true);
serializer.startTag("", "Document");
for(int i = 0 ; i < myList.size(); i++) {
serializer.startTag("", "sms");
serializer.startTag(null, "sender");
serializer.text(newSms.getsender());
serializer.endTag(null, "sender");          
serializer.endTag("", "sms");
}           
serializer.endTag("", "Document");
serializer.endDocument();
serializer.flush();
fileos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
Log.e("Exception", "error occurred while creating xml file");
}
}
```

the result is wrong

it's not returning the right result i want to have 
it's just repeating the same wrong number " 44225627565 "
and i don't know where is te problem

Comment: What's the problem? Specify how the output should look like and post the code to createXml().

Comment: i just edited my post

Comment: This is the result that i'm getting

<sms>

    <sender>+44225627565</sender>

  </sms>

  <sms>

    <sender>+44225627565</sender>
  </sms>
  <sms>
    <sender>+44225627565</sender>
  </sms>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want probably iterate over `myList`, what you are doing here:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < myList.size(); i++) {
    serializer.startTag("", "sms");
    serializer.startTag(null, "sender");
    serializer.text(newSms.getsender());  <----
    serializer.endTag(null, "sender");          
    serializer.endTag("", "sms");
}
```

But you are using `newSms.getsender()` to receive the number. 
Which is responsible for getting always the same number.
Instead you should use: `myList.get(i).getsender()` or whatever myList includes.

**EDIT**
You also insert always the same object into your list:

```
newSms.setsender(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
myList.add(newSms);
```

You should always create a new object for inserting:

```
Sms tmp = new Sms();
tmp.setsender(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("address")));
myList.add(tmp);
```

Comment: I changed  serializer.text(newSms.getsender());
into  serializer.text(myList.get(i).getsender())
but I'm getting the same result !

Comment: Have a look at my edit, but keep also `serializer.text(myList.get(i).getsender())`